# Deploying microservices node js app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, kubernetes, web-deployment, minikube

I have a microservices app with node js and express js and react js .and i m using docker and minikube and skaffold . And i want to deploy it to azure or heroku .

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy to Microsoft Azure you need to follow this steps:

1. Create a Kubernetes cluster flowing this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal).
2. Create your Kubernetes manifests files for each applications or using Helm .
3. After that deploy your application.

For Heroku you can deploy your image directly without need to Kubernetes .

I hope that this steps can help you to deploy your application.